# Nesting algebraic handlers from separate modules

Tags: ocaml

Can algebraic handlers in OCaml be separated and put into different modules, then be nested together in some other file?

For instance, say you have a program in a file called `program.ml` that uses a user-defined function `put: int -> unit` that modifies a variable `x`. In this scenario, there is an effect `Put_found: int -> unit Effect.t` and `put` is defined as

```ml
put n = x:= n; perform(Put_found n)
```

A sample program would look like: `put(5);put(0)`.

There are also two compilation units `Handler1` and `Handler2`, each with their ml and mli files. The former contains a function `run_h1` that when given the sample program as input, the handler acts on the effect `Put_found` by printing the integer passed to it. Then, it raises another effect `Report_p`, which is to be passed to the second handler. `run_h1` returns a function of type `unit -> unit` as looks like this:

```
let run_h1 () = fun () -> match_with Program.comp () {
effc = (fun (type c) (eff: c Effect.t) ->
    match eff with
    | Put_found s -> Some (fun (k : (c,_) continuation) ->
            report_p(s); continue k ())
    | _ -> None
  );
}
```

The second effect, `Report_p` of type `int -> unit Effect.t`, is to be handled by a function found in `Handler2` such that if the integer passed is negative, an error message is printed to the screen.

`run_h2` is the following function:

```
let run_h2 inst x = match_with inst x
{
    effc = (fun (type b) (eff: b Effect.t) ->
      match eff with
      | Report n -> Some (fun (k: (b,_) continuation) -> 
        if n = (-1) then printf "Put with value -1 encountered.\n" else printf "Put found with allowed value.\n"; continue k ())
      | _ -> None
    );
    exnc = raise;
    retc = fun x-> x
}
```

In another file, `run_handlers.ml`, I make use of the compilation units mentioned above as follows:

```ml
let run_handlers () = Handler2.run_h2(Handler1.run_h1 ()) ()
```

When at first the program and effects were found in the same file and the handlers were nested in the same file, the program worked fine. Here is what it looked like:
The program looked like this:

```
let run_h2 () = 
  let comp () = put(5); put(6); put(-1); put(100) in
  let run_h1 () = match_with comp ()
  { effc = (fun (type c) (eff: c Effect.t) ->
      match eff with
      | Put_found s -> Some (fun (k: (c,_) continuation) ->
              report_p(s); continue k ())
      | _ -> None
    );
    exnc = raise;
    retc = fun x-> x
  } in
  match_with run_h1 () {
    effc = (fun (type b) (eff: b Effect.t) ->
      match eff with
      | Report n -> Some (fun (k: (b,_) continuation) -> 
        if n = (-1) then printf "Put with value -1 encountered.\n" else printf "Put found with value: %d\n" (n); continue k ())
      | _ -> None
    );
    exnc = raise;
    retc = fun x-> x
  }
```

Now, I am trying to modularise it, but a `Stdlib.Effect.Unhandled` exception was thrown on the first instance the effect should be performed.

Comment: You should describe your actual problem, with an example of the actual failure that you are trying to solve. Otherwise it is hard to answer to you beyond "yes, values and types can be defined in separate modules".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the effect constructors were not being shared across `Handler1` and `Handler2`, so, it's as if the constructors were different and that is why the handlers didn't recognise the effects. Once I put the effects in one file, then shared this amongst the compilation units, the problem is fixed.